# Simple CICD workflow for small-scale deployments?

Tags: jenkins, devops, teamcity, pipeline, cicd

I work for a small startup. We have 3 environments (Production, Development, and Staging) and GitHub is used as VCS.

All env runs on EC2 with docker.

Can someone suggest me a simple CICD solution that can trigger builds automatically after certain branches are merged / manual trigger option?

Like, if anything in merged into dev-merge, build and deploy to development, and the same for staging and pushing the image to ECR and rolling out docker update.

We tried Jenkins but we felt it was over-complicated for our small-scale infra.

GitHub actions are also evaluated (self-hosted runners), but it needs YAMLs to be there in repos.

We are looking for something that can give us option to modify the pipeline or overall flow without code-hosted CICD config. (Like the way Jenkins gives option to either use Jenkins file or configure the job manually via GUI)

Any opinions about Team City?

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this, not because it's a bad question but because it's a better question for a forum or Reddit, and generally devops questions belong on the devops stackexchange. I would strongly advise against TeamCity though, because the license fees can be ridiculous. I also recommend keeping your pipelines in code for many reasons, even if it's not in the same repo as the projects being built — configuration as code is standard practice, including for pipelines.

Comment: Hello @ZacAnger, thanks for the inputs.
I will move the question to DevOps StackExchange, also I forgot to mention that we are looking for self-hosted CICD, we were thinking to try Self Hosted Teamcity...

 I will also take a look at configuration as a code for pipelines as you mentioned.

Comment: What is your issue with YAML being in repos? That is considered best practice now.

Comment: In that case, we should try config as a code then!
Our repos are not maintained properly in terms of the branches (Sad reality)

Comment: I didn't know Jetbrains had a cloud plan. With self-hosted TeamCity you pay per build agent, so once you have a need for more than 3 build agents (3 concurrent builds, or 3 builds that need to run on different platforms) you're suddenly spending a significant amount of money (besides the cost of the VMs for the agents).

Comment: Zac I don't think the price is the only point you should include in your evaluation of a tool. TeamCity has many positive points which would be quite appealing to a small-scale deployment in a small team/company.

Comment: @ZacAnger the licence limit is applied to simultaneously running agents. you could create multiple cloud agent images for every platform, which will be started on demand in your k8s/aws (but not more than 3 at once, so you should wait for another agent to finish until next one could be started).

Comment: @VladimirShefer in the original version of the question, they said that Jenkins seemed to be too complex for their needs, which means setting up ephemeral build agents on K8s would surely have also been too much to deal with.